Marginalisation with respect to arbitrary distribution
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $X: \Omega\rightarrow\mathcal{X}$ and $Y: \Omega\rightarrow\mathcal{Y}$ be random variables.
Now, I know that
$$\int_{C}\mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(D)\mathbb{P}_{X}(dx)=\mathbb{P}_{X,Y}(C,D),$$
which defines a joint distribution on $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$
I also know that
$$\int_{\mathcal{X}}\mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(D)\mathbb{P}_{X}(dx)=\mathbb{P}_{Y}(D),$$
which defines a distribution on $\mathcal{Y}$.
My question is now what happens if we substitute in these equation the marginal distribution $\mathbb{P}_X$ by an arbitrary probability measure on $\mathcal{X}$ call it $\mu$? I.e. is
$$\int_{C}\mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(D)\mu(dx)$$
still a joint distribution on
$\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$?
And is
$$\int_{\mathcal{X}}\mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(D)\mu(dx)$$
still a distribution on $\mathcal{Y}$ that does not depend on $x$ anymore,  i.e., has $x$
been marginalised out as well?

This is a classical set-up as can be formally stated as the Product Measure Theorem: if $(\Omega_1, \mathscr F_1) $ and $(\Omega_2, \mathscr F_2) $ are measurable spaces and $\mu_1$ is a $\sigma$–finite measure on $\mathscr F_1$ and $\mu$ is a transition kernel on $\mathscr F_2\times \Omega_1$ such that $\mu(\cdot, \omega_1) $ is uniformly $\sigma$–finite for each $\omega_1\in \Omega_1, $ then there exists a unique measure $\underline\mu$ on $\mathscr F:=\sigma(\mathscr F_1\times \mathscr F_2) $ such that for $F\in\mathscr F$ $$\underline{\mu}(F) =\int_{\Omega_1} \mu(F(\omega_1), \omega_1)~ \mu(\mathrm d\omega_1). \tag 1\label 1$$
Here in the OP, $\mu$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal X;~\mathbb P_{Y\mid X~=~x}$ is a Markov kernel on $\mathscr F_2\times \mathcal X.$ Then by Product Measure Theorem, this leads to a unique measure $\mathsf P$ on $\mathcal X\times \mathcal Y$ such that for $C\times D\in\mathscr F, $ akin to $\eqref 1,$ $$\mathsf P(C\times D) =  \int_{C}\mathbb{P}_{Y\mid X~=~x}(D,x)~\mu(\mathrm dx).$$
--
Reference:
$\rm[I]$ Real Analysis and Probability, Robert Ash, Academic Press, $1972, $ sec. $2.6$

thank you for your answer and reference! What I still dont understand is how the marginalisation would look like. I.e., we know that
$$\int_{\mathcal{X}}\mathbb{P}{Y|X=x}(D)\mathbb{P}{X}(dx)=\mathbb{P}{Y}(D),$$
i.e., that marginalising w.r.t. the marginal distribution of $X$ gives the marginal distribtuino of $Y$. But I assume if we marginalise w.r.t. to $\mu$ we wont get the marginal distribution of $Y$. So what do we get in
$$\int{\mathcal{X}}\mathbb{P}_{Y|X=x}(D)\mu(dx)$$

There would be nothing intimidating here. For the first case, it was leading to $\mathbb P_{X, Y}(\mathcal X\times Y^{-1}(D)) . $ Same would happen for the latter case with $\mathbb P_{X, Y}$ replaced by $\mathsf P. $

It would be "marginalized".

Ah thank you, so we can say, that it will be a distribution on $\mathcal{Y}$ and that it will not depend on $x$ anymore?
